# Mental JSON cartwheels, match values by key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON object:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e0a" : false,
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e06" : true,
        "58eedc4198d1712b870c8e05" : true
    },
    "bar" : {
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e0a" : "git",
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e06" : "svn",
        "58eedc4198d1712b870c8e05" : "hg"
    },
}
```

I want to get an object that looks like:

```
{
  git: false,
  svn: true,
  hg: true
}
```

every algorithm I have come up with is very verbose, anybody think of something quick and clever?

Comment: note that in theory we need to safeguard against the possibility of one object having a different number of key/value pairs than the other.

Comment: so then what happens if they're different. And you may as well show what you've attempted, since you might be on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newObj = {};

for (let property in obj.bar) {
    if obj.bar.hasOwnProperty(property){
      newObj[obj.bar[property]] = obj.foo[property];
    }
}
```

I'm really *not* a js dev, but this is where I would start.

*The code above is written without any kind of syntax checking.  I have no idea if it will actually compile.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) (if not you should), you can do in following way.

```
  var _ = require("lodash");

var data = {
    "foo": {
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e0a": false,
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e06": true,
        "58eedc4198d1712b870c8e05": true
    },
    "bar": {
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e0a": "git",
        "58eedc4298d1712b870c8e06": "svn",
        "58eedc4198d1712b870c8e05": "hg",
        "58eedc4198d1712b870c8e06": "fa"

    },
}
var keys = _.keys(data.bar);
var result = {};
_.forEach(keys, function (key) {
    result[data.bar[key]] = data.foo[key] ? data.foo[key] : false;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Object.keys() and keys.forEach() should be ok. Maybe lodash has something more powerful for this situation?